# Making Google Web Toolkit applications accessible externally

Tags: gwt

I've noticed when I start my application from within eclipse (Run -> Run as Web Application) I can access my application externally by using the machine's public IP address.  However when I run from the command line (ant devmode) I can only access from localhost.  What changes do I need to make so that I can run from the command line and access externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out

ant -Dgwt.args="-bindAddress 0.0.0.0" devmode

Comment: Yes, that's correct. http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/release_notes.html#Release_Notes_2_0_1 notes that as of GWT 2.0.1 "The development mode server will, by default, only bind to localhost which will break cross-machine debugging. You can get the old behavior by specifying -bindAddress 0.0.0.0. Please see issue (#4322) for more details. For webAppCreator-generated ant files, you can pass this with ant -Dgwt.args="-bindAddress 0.0.0.0" devmode."